# react native not run in debug mode

Tags: react-native

I have a redmi note 3 device
When I connect device via usb and run `react-native run-android`  this is what i've got
[image: empty screen]

No red screen error
If I close the app , then run the packager and open it again I have the app works but debug menu not works by shaking or pressing menu button
What is going wrong here?

Comment: Can you please explain more: like what codes you have written 
or did you try to run a fresh project?

Comment: @Dpkstr i've found the problem . that was because of xiaomi `display popup` permision in settings